# Android Error in opening framebuffer device

Tags: android, framebuffer

In Android, I am trying to open framebuffer device, using NDK code, as below:

fd = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY)

I am getting the fd result value as -1. My device is rooted and I have declared "android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER" permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Is there any additional steps, I should do?

Comment: While installing is there a message in logcat that indicates you don't get the permission?

Comment: No, there is no message in logcat regarding permission.

Comment: The frame buffer manifest permission won't do you any good as it cannot be granted to 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 0):

try this
it worked for me

adb shell chmod 06755 /dev/graphics/fb0

Comment: This would only work on a rooted device, and would not be persistent across reboots.